# How can I select the array object having the lower price field value directly into the HTML of this Angular application?

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

into an HTML page of an Angular application on which I am working I have this tag interpolating a value showing the price of a product:

```
<h3 class="product-price" *ngIf="isApproved && canShowPrices;">
    {{wine.formats[0].price | number:'0.2-2'}} € <span class="product-price-unit">/Unit.</span>
</h3>
```

So as you can see it is showing this value: **wine.formats[0].price** that is the **price** field value of the first object into the **formats** array.

Now this **formats** array can contain multiple objects having different prices. Exist a way to select the object (into the **formats** array) having the lower price? Instead to select the first object of the array I want to select the object having the lower price and show this value.

Is it possible do it directly into the HTML page? (maybe using a pipe)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very bare example (not handling empty array, not checking null price, assuming price is always a number...):

```
@Pipe({ name: 'lowerPrice' })
export class LowerPricePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: { price: number }[]): number {
    const prices = items.map(item => {
      return item.price;
    });
    return Math.min(...prices);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes... it is possible to do this directly in the HTML markup using a pipe. I would encourage you to use a custom pipe for this.